# ValueError: object too deep for desired array In np.digitize function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do image quantization using np.digitize function but keep getting the "too deep" error.
according to the documentation, both 2d and 1d arrays are supported, but none worked for me.
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

def quant_img(img, N):
    bins = np.array([range(0,N)])
    inds = np.digitize(img, bins)
    return inds

img = mpimg.imread("img.jpg")     
gray = rgb2gray(img)
gray_qaunt = quant_img(gray,10)
```

and the error is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f751f38c519e> in <module>()
     17 gray = rgb2gray(img)
---> 18 gray_qaunt = quant_img(gray,10)


<ipython-input-30-f751f38c519e> in quant_img(img, N)
---> 13     inds = np.digitize(img, bins)
     14     return inds


ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Edit: I've also tryed to bin with a 1d array, but it didn't work as well

```
def quant_img(img, N):
    bins = np.array([range(0,N)])
    img = np.array(img.flatten())
    inds = np.digitize(img, bins)
    return inds
```

Edit:  Thanks to @Warren Weckesser I've noticed that `np.array(range(0,X))` is in fact a 2d array, what caused the problem.

Comment: Debugging tip: if a function generates an error mysteriously, check that all the arguments being passed to the function are correct.  In this case, take a closer look at the `bins` argument.  The docstring for `digitize` says `bins` must be one-dimensional and monotonic.  Is it?  Check, for example, `bins.shape`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using [np.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) I'd suggest that you check numpy version as in the docs it says this about input value:

> Input array to be binned. Prior to NumPy 1.10.0, this array had to be
>   1-dimensional, but can now have any shape.

Comment: As I mentioned, it doesn't work both with 1d and 2d arrays, I've updated the question with the 1d array that doesn't work as well